# WPF Opacities guidelines

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, window

After reading a lot of documentation I don't have reasonably clear how to use all the opacity's WPF Window lets me use:

```
Window.Opacity 
Window.Background.Opacity 
Window.Background.Color.Alpha
```

I saw that `Window.Opacity` affects child elements opacity, not as `Background.Opacity` and `Background.color.Alpha`
When and how are the correct ways to use these elements in the design of WPF UIs?

When do I have to use overall Opacity?

What is the performance penalty of using one instead of other?

Comment: if you want to change background opacity not child elements, you can do somthing like <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Window.Background>

Comment: Good questions and deserves a nice blog, however this is waaaaay too broad

Comment: @TheGeneral A very very light and simple explanation is enough for me.